# Binary Search Specifics

Tags: java, binary-search

I am hoping someone can help me understand this code for binary search. This is from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/126/template-ii/937/), it is "Template 2" under Binary Search.

I was wondering why you set right to nums.length
-Is there a reason why it isn't nums.length - 1 ?

```
int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target){
  if(nums == null || nums.length == 0)
    return -1;

  int left = 0, right = nums.length;
  while(left < right){
    // Prevent (left + right) overflow
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if(nums[mid] == target){ return mid; }
    else if(nums[mid] < target) { left = mid + 1; }
    else { right = mid; }
  }

  // Post-processing:
  // End Condition: left == right
  if(left != nums.length && nums[left] == target) return left;
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: I guess because otherwise the last element will never be inspected

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? isn't nums[nums.length-1] the last element?

Comment: But that `nums[right]` is never inspected. Notice that it stops when `left == right`, so you never get a chane to look at `nums[right]`. You can see other evidence that it's using an endpoint-exclusive range, such as calculating the midpoint as `(right - left) / 2` rather than `(right - left + 1) / 2`.

Comment: Isn't that nums[right] checked in the end condition?

Comment: The first half checks that `left != length`, so it never checks the right'th element.

Comment: This is not C++. Looks more like Java to me. Edited tags.